# What is the policy for directing questions to other websites (forums)?

Tags: discussion, policy

Twice today I found myself wanting to tell a questioner that s(he) would be better served by turning to a distribution-specific forum. Is there a Stack Exchange policy about this?

references: [Kali Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420696/apt-get-update-error-in-kali-linux/420699?noredirect=1#comment756472_420699), [Linux Mint question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420801/how-to-get-computer-working-that-always-boots-into-blackscreen)

Comment: [When recommend an appropriate site for off-topic question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268722/839601) "Every Stack Exchange site... has Help Center pages... Unless you are positive that you have read and understood these pages, it is safer to abstain of recommending the site..."

Answer (score 5):

In many cases - you probably are better off not doing so. People may get annoyed at the perception that you're promoting an off site research, and there's *fundamental* issues related to the two example questions which can, and might already be taken care of.

Kali Linux is a bit of a sore point for U&L, In my opinion, quite a lot of folks get dumped into the distro with illusions that it will make them a great hacker, without actual teaching of the fundamentals of the Linux platform. It's a disservice, and the point of the parent question is to point them at useful resources for knowing what's happening - [you can find more context here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4640/what-should-we-do-about-kali-linux-questions).

The second question could use more comments. You have a user who has no idea where to start, and an off site resource isn't going to make the question any clearer. There's no answers because as is, Unless you had the same model of laptop, and had the same issues and solved it - there's nothing but "it doesn't work."

Considering SE's goals, if an off-site resource isn't a *reference* that is part of a more complete answer, it's probably not really going to be welcome. Imagine if people kept posting links to say, SE on Quora. Unless a post *anywhere* explicitly asks for a link to a forum (which, in turn would be off topic here), it is just bad etiquette.